# How to add Error in custom visualforce page and also rollback

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to insert 2 objects and catch the error and show it in visualforce page but when I catch the error of second object first object I insert do not get rollback.

```
                 lead objlead = new lead(); 
                 objlead = data;
                 try{  
                    upsert objlead;
                    } 
           catch(DMLException e){

                       ApexPages.addMessages(e);
                       return null;
                }

                 test__c objtest = new test__c();
                 objtest = objWrap.objeoi;
                 objtest.Lead__c = objlead.id;
                  try{  
                     insert objeoi;
                    } 
           catch(DMLException e){


                        ApexPages.addMessages(e);
                        return null;
                }
```

i use roll-back but it is not good solution. i want alternative.

Comment: Please explain why Roll back is not a good solution??

Comment: when we define a savepoint it takes the snap of entire database. A system has no idea what is going to change in its database after that. and when an error occurs it will put it to that database point. so my concern is when 50 users are using a same visual force page and error occur in one person it will affect other user data as well.

Comment: Is it just your thought or it happened to you, because in my opinion every user has their own transaction and i think it only rollbacks that transaction.

Comment: ok thanks, I am currently using the same. Hope it will not affect other user data. thanks for your time @Mr.Frodo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you can use `Database.setSavePoint` to rollback and show error message, Multiple users using same page shouldn't have any problem because every user has their own transaction:

```
Savepoint dbSave = Database.setSavepoint();  
try{  
    insert myObj;
    insert myOtherObj;
}catch(DMLException e){ //undo all of the failed operation.
    ApexPages.addMessages(e);
    Database.rollback(dbSave);

}
```

Comment: yes I did the same but database.setsavepoint() take the snap of entire database and it 50 users are using it. and one makes an error then entire database gets rollback.

Comment: @ajayrawat Are you sure, I think every user has their own transaction. AFAIK it shouldn't rollback other user's transactions.

Comment: @ajayrawat Database.setSavepoint doesn't "take the snap of entire database." It creates a transaction restore point, where any changes that occur *in the current transaction* are tracked, and can be rolled back with Database.rollback. Two users performing actions at the exact same time won't affect each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the

```
upsert(recordToUpsert, externalIdField, allOrNone)
```

type of the upsert method. With the last parameter you can say that you don't want to upsert any records of one fails.

Comment: but they are 2 different objects if I do this problem remains the same. if error occur in second object it will not insert 2 object but still insert the first one.